# Ordenar texto com números em javascript

Tags: javascript

Pessoal tenho essa situação.

Após montar uma array, com informações de área e valor:

Área 9 - 45, Área 8 - 70, Área 7 - 100, Área 5 - 75, Área 3 - 110, Área 2 - 145, Área 14 - 20, Área 11 - 60, Área 10 - 70, Área 1 - 40

Preciso que fique dessa ordenado pelo valor maior, sem levar em consideração a Área, mas a informação da Área deve ficar junto com o valor.

Área 2 - 145, Área 3 - 110, Área 7 - 100, Área 5 - 75, Área 10 - 70, Área 8 - 70, Área 11 - 60, Área 9 - 45, Área 1 - 40, Área 14 - 20

Aqui esta o código que retorna a primeira informação:

```
function InserirSomatoriaArea(){




    var filtro1 = "?$filter=(Title%20ne%20'')%20and%20(Pontuacao%20ne%20'')"
    var dado1 = GetListItems('600862F-1E0E-4442-A95B-96235C460CA0', filtro1);

    var valor1=[];

    var filtroarea = "?$filter=(Title%20ne%20'')"
    var dado2 = GetListItems('600286F-1E0E-4442-A95B-96235C460CA0', filtroarea);

    var valorarea=[];
    var valorareaT=[];

    for (var it = 0; it < dado2.length; it++) {

        valorarea[it]=dado2[it].Title;

    }

    valorarea.sort(sortfunction); 

    function sortfunction(a, b){
        if (a < b) return -1; 
        if (a > b) return 1;
    }

    var arr_unique = [...new Set(valorarea)];


    //alert(arr_unique)

    var somaarea = 0;


    for (var it = 0; it < arr_unique.length; it++) {

        for (var itt = 0; itt < dado1.length; itt++) {

            if (arr_unique[it] == dado2[itt].Title){

            somaarea += Number(dado2[itt].Pontuacao);   


            }
        }

        MatrizSArea[it] = arr_unique[it] + " - " + somaarea ;
        MatrizSArea.sort(sortfunction1)
        somaarea=0;

    }
    alert (MatrizSArea)
    function sortfunction1(a, b){

        if (a < b) return 1;
        //if (a > b) return 1;
    }


}
```

Comment: A sua questão está um pouco vaga. Vejo vários `sorts` pelo código fora.  Não estão a funcionar ? O que faz o código em si ? Qual o array que pretende ordenar ? De que forma esta essa informação nesse array ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você pode fazer a ordenação, chamando a função **sort()** da seguinte forma:

```
fruits.sort(function(a, b){return Number(a.substring(a.indexOf('-')+1, a.length).trim()) < Number(b.substring(b.indexOf('-')+1, b.length).trim())})
```

Comment: Esse é um exemplo de ordenação só trocar o nome do array que deve funcionar de forma correta, ordenando decrescente pelo valor. Como é mostrado funcionando no seguinte https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FPN1TUEJWN6N